# Why is it wrong to say "an ancient Athenian neighborhood settled on the fourth century BC."

Tags: exam-questions, participles

> While diging the foundation, builders discovered the remains of an ancient Athenian neighborhood ____ the fourth century BC.  ( An ACT exam question)

why can't I insert "settled on" as an post-modifer to the sentence? I don't think there is any syntactical errors.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense for at least two reasons:

1. A 'neighbourhood' is an area or district. An area can't move, so how can it settle somewhere?
2. The fourth century BC isn't a place, it is a time. How can something settle in a time?

My guess would be the answer is "from". You can say something is 'from' a time.

Comment: I think "settled" is past participle modifying "neighborhood," which can be equivalent to something like "neighborhood was settled on ... by (unidentified people)"  
As to the second point, I understand it as the neighborhood was settled during that time.

Comment: @crucifyficklecrank a 'settlement' is a place where people have settled to live. In doing so they create a neighbourhood. So it can't be a neighbourhood before it has been a settlement, and there's no sense in saying both.

Comment: My neighbourhood was settled **in 1865**, when the first houses were buit, and people started living in them.